# How does an application in linux knows the available bandwidth for data transfer(any daemon helps it?)

Tags: backup, bandwidth

I am trying to understanding a backup application working and during the staging of the data and uploading to cloud, it sends data as per the available bandwidth. How does it know the available bandwidth at the moment? Does it use any other application to get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically no other application is involved.

Speed.negotiation over TCP/IP has built in controls like buffers and acknowledgements which control the speeds.

If speeds are variable and/or conditions change, TCP will deliberately drop packets to strongly signal to the sender to slow down, after which speed gradually increases until another dropped packet etc...